# Setting up awesomium in netbeans 8.00 for c++

Tags: netbeans, awesomium

I'm struggling to configure netbeans 8.0 with c++ to work with awesomium
(http://wiki.awesomium.com/getting-started/setting-up-on-windows.html)

I've tried using full paths, environmental variables and even netbeans default pathing for the "Additional Include Directories", "Additional Library Directories" and " Additional Dependencies".

Still no luck, i get the below error:

```
make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target `awesomium.lib'
```

Please help if you can, I have built the project on VS Express and it builds fine but I love netbeans as I also do PHP and app dev so would like all my projects on 1 IDE